# how to remove duplicate lines of a huge file in python

Tags: python, file, duplicates, line

I have a txt file around 32GB and need to check whether there are some duplicate lines or not.
What is the best way to remove duplicate lines of a huge text file without reading it line by line?

Comment: By reading it line by line. If you don't read the file, how do you plan to identify duplicates?

Comment: i am open to listen any magic, but i think without reading something you can not know what it is. and without knowing what it actually is, you can not compare it to other thing, thus can not reveal one is duplicate of other, or not. i think you should explore the methods of how to effectively read and remove duplicates given a memory and computation power constraints.

Comment: Is it possible to have the whole file in memory with your environment?

Comment: @dawg no, it isn't possible

Comment: Your best bet then is some form of line-by-line hashing. If your basic record is a line, and you cannot hold the entire file in memory, you must read the file line-by-line. Python is good at that and super fast.

Comment: Just a thought: What about reading the file some bytes at a time and every line separator (\n) you remember the start, the end and a hash of the line you just read. If you generate a hash more than once, you know from which byte to which byte you have a duplicate line.

Comment: Your problem is more how to process a big file without loading it entirely in memory rather than how to remove duplicates lines without reading the file.

Comment: The answer I am giving is assuming you meant "without reading the whole file in memory" rather than "without reading the file line by line". The former is possible, the latter, not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make a set of the lines seen so far, and to save memory, store a hash of each line instead of the line itself (at the cost of a minuscule chance of false positive):

```py
seen = set()
with open('src-text.txt', 'r') as fin, open('src-text-unique.txt', 'w') as fout:
    for line in fin:
        h = hash(line)
        if h not in seen:
            fout.write(line)
            seen.add(h)
```

**Notes**:

- if you are worried about the 64-bit hash collision, you may use a different hash, such as `hashlib.md5()` or `hashlib.sha256()` instead.
- if instead you don't have enough memory for the hashes of lines, you may look at a BloomFilter instead for a finite use of memory (at the expense of a higher false positive rate).
- as a third alternative, somewhat inspired by @dawg's idea of "decorating the lines", if you are really too tight in memory for either storing all the hashes or a large-enough BloomFilter, you could split your file in `n_parts`, according to `hash(line) % n_parts`; in these temp files, store the original line number along with each line. Then apply deduplication for each part separately, and then merge (the already-sorted part-files). This avoids the `n log n` sort and is instead `O(n)`. That technique, however, is not applicable to stream processing, whereas the first two (set of hashes or BloomFilter) are, until the number of distinct items is too large and leads to either MemoryError (set of hashes) or too large a false positive rate (BloomFilter).

---

**Addendum: Short analysis of collision rates and memory size**:

Let's say that your 32GB file has lines of 60 chars on average, and 10% of the lines are duplicates (90% distinct lines).

That would lead to:

```py
n_distinct = int(0.9 * 32 * 1024**3 / 60)
>>> n_distinct
515_396_075
```

In other words, about 1/2 billion distinct lines. That's the number of hashes we'd have to store in memory, and the `n` value in a BloomFilter analysis.

Size and collision probability of hashes:

Referring to the well-known formulas for estimating the probability of collision described in [Birthday attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_attack), and using the first two terms of the Taylor expansion of 1 - e<sup>-x</sup> ≈ x - x<sup>2</sup>/2, we get a probability of collision for well-distributed hashes of `n` bits and `k` distinct items as:

```py
def prob_collision(n_bits, n_distinct):
    n, k = n_bits, n_distinct  # usual notation
    x = k**2 / 2**(n + 1)
    return x - x**2 / 2  # approx of 1 - exp(-x)
```

- Using the built-in `hash()`, each hash is a 64-bit int: 8 bytes. So we'd need 3.8GiB in memory. The probability of at least one collision (meaning: at least one line wrongly identified as having been seen when in fact it was not) in the entire file is 0.7%.
- Using `md5` (128 bits), you'd need double the memory, 7.7GiB, but get a collision probability of 3.9*10<sup>-22</sup>.

Size and collision probability of Bloom Filter:

A [Bloom Filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter) with `m` bits and intended to store up to `n` items should use the optimal number of hash functions that minimizes the rate of false positives: `k = m / n * log(2)`. With that number of functions, the false positive rate (FPR) is roughly: (1 - e<sup>-kn/m</sup>)<sup>k</sup>. The probability of at least one collision is (much) less than `FPR * n` (it is roughly the integral of FPR for n in 0..n_distinct).

```py
def bloom_k(m, n):
    return int(np.ceil(m / n * np.log(2)))

def bloom_false_positive_rate(m, n, k=None):
    k = bloom_k(m, n) if k is None else k
    fpos = np.power(1 - np.exp(-k*n/m), k)
    return fpos

def bloom_prob_collision(m, n, k=None):
    # too lazy to figure out the integral, so
    # using this instead which is slow as molasses
    k = bloom_k(m, n) if k is None else k
    i = np.arange(0, n + 1)
    p_coll = np.sum(np.power(1 - np.exp(-k*i/m), k))
    return p_coll
```

- Using the same amount of memory as what `n_distinct` 64-bit hashes indicated above (3.8Gib), we get `m = 32_641_751_449` bits, `k = 44` hashing functions, and a probability of at least one collision that is much smaller: roughly 0.0001%.

Comment: your code results in a memory error

Answer (score 1):

As stated in comments, your issue is processing a file that is bigger than your computer's memory. Deduplicating is usually trivial.

The best way to handle this is likely a decorate, sort, undecorate "DSU" approach with:

1. Create a TEMP file and Decorate each line with:

   a) A hash large enough to identify duplicates -- the built-in `hash()` is great of SHA 256 is likely bullet proof;

   b) The line number.
2. Sort based on the hash key using one of the many algorithms to sort large files
3. Eliminate the proximate duplicates found
4. Re sort based on the line number
5. Undecorate back to the new file.

This assumes that a hash of each line does not fit in memory. If that hash DOES fit in memory, use [Pierre D's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66987448/298607).

Comment: you may also just use a BloomFilter, and even run a few times with different salt to achieve a level of false positives that satisfies your needs.